# Too many Fragments causing OutOfMemory error

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm making an app that uses a bottom navigation bar (BottomBar) on its MainActivity. A FrameLayout is positioned above the BottomBar. Every time an icon in the bottom bar is clicked, the tab's fragment is inserted into the FrameLayout using FragmentTransaction's replace() function. That inserted fragment contains ViewPager, which results in more fragment launching and caching. Right now, there is only one Activity but many Fragments. I haven't load any data and I'm already receiving a OutOfMemory Exception even after setting the maxHeapSize to 4gb.

What can I do to improve the performance without changing the UI (still have a bottom navigation bar and each tab contains a viewpager)?

Comment: Please show some of the code you have.

Comment: `maxHeapSize` is and IDE (gradle) feature, this has nothing to do with the OOM error which is thrown in the app.

Comment: Are you using `addToBackStack()` on your `FragmentTransaction`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I didn't use `addToBackStack()`

Comment: Try adding Logs to OnCreate and OnDestroy to make sure fragments are getting destroyed.